# can someone please help me I am lost i transfered coins from paxfull to bitcoin core

Tags: wallet-recovery

I bought bitcoins to pay a bill. which never happened because of something called protcal? IDK.
then i read online that bitcoincore was a good wallett to transfer and pay bills. now I have no idea how to use it or see them. someone please help.. dumb damsal in destress

Comment: Using what service did you attempt to buy the coins? You'll need to set up a wallet of some sort in order to receive/send bitcoins, if bitcoin core is too complicated there are simpler wallets available (such as a mobile wallet on your phone).

Comment: yes well I just read if you have an older laptop...it wont sync...thats what the app on my laptop says....weeks it will take weekds...

Answer (score 1):

You can download bitcoin-core from [here](https://bitcoin.org/download)

But it's not highly recommended since you may need to download the whole blockchain.

What I recommended as an alternative is Electrum since you can use public bitcoin servers without downloading the whole blockchain

Comment: Is highly recommended if you can run it, it is the reference client but, it requires downloading the entire blockchain.